# The service configuration is `nil`

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, info.plist

The AWS docs needs updating I believe.
after connecting the backend, 
- I have enabled user sign in "Email and password"
- I have added the awsconfiguration.json

This is error I get at run :

> 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` before using this method.'

This is my **info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>amazonaws.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>amazonaws.com.cn</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>AWS</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CredentialsProvider</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CognitoIdentity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Default</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>PoolId</key>
                    <string>us-east-1:703c8a9c-2bf5-4879-8e45-29cd270ad9fc</string>
                    <key>Region</key>
                    <string>us-east-1</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>S3TransferManager</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>us-east-1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>S3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>us-east-1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Has anyone ever been through the steps of enabling and implementing user sign-in. Which part is missing please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47889044/1801544 ?

Comment: I tried that. It did not help